# PL/SQL: ORA-29481: Implicit results cannot be returned to client

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have migrated below procedure MYSQL to ORACLE and Migrated version is also given below. 
Migrated procedure has been successfully complied but when we run this procedure in SQL Developer with respective parameter to print the "v_refcur" SYS_REFCURSOR result
It gives me ERROR: ORA-29481: Implicit results cannot be returned to client

--- Source Mysql  Procedure-----------------------------------------

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `get_police_station_for_hierarchy` ;

DELIMITER $$

 CREATE  PROCEDURE `get_police_station_for_hierarchy`(officecd BIGINT,pstsaffcd VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE table_count INT;
DECLARE officerInCharge VARCHAR(20);
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS   temp1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS   temp2;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS  temp3;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS  temp4;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 (cd BIGINT,off_level INT);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2 (cd BIGINT,off_level INT);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp3 (cd BIGINT,off_level INT);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp4 (cd BIGINT,off_level INT);

 SELECT OFFICE_INCHARGE_CD INTO officerInCharge FROM m_office_types  WHERE OFFICE_CD=officecd ;
 IF(officerInCharge=pstsaffcd) THEN
INSERT INTO temp1 
SELECT m_office_hierarchy.OFFICE_CD,m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD FROM m_office_hierarchy,m_office_types WHERE SUPERVISOR_OFFICE_CD =officecd
AND m_office_hierarchy.office_cd=m_office_types.office_cd AND m_office_hierarchy.lang_cd=m_office_types.lang_cd AND m_office_hierarchy.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D'
AND m_office_types.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' AND m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD=7;
INSERT INTO temp2 
SELECT m_office_hierarchy.OFFICE_CD,m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD FROM m_office_hierarchy,m_office_types WHERE SUPERVISOR_OFFICE_CD=officecd
AND m_office_hierarchy.office_cd=m_office_types.office_cd AND m_office_hierarchy.lang_cd=m_office_types.lang_cd
AND m_office_hierarchy.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' AND m_office_types.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' AND m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD <> 7 ;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO table_count FROM temp2;
WHILE (table_count>0)
DO 
INSERT INTO temp1 
SELECT m_office_hierarchy.OFFICE_CD,m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD FROM m_office_hierarchy,m_office_types WHERE SUPERVISOR_OFFICE_CD IN (SELECT cd FROM temp2)
AND m_office_hierarchy.office_cd=m_office_types.office_cd AND m_office_hierarchy.lang_cd=m_office_types.lang_cd
 AND m_office_hierarchy.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' AND m_office_types.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' AND m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD=7;
INSERT INTO temp3 
SELECT m_office_hierarchy.OFFICE_CD,m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD FROM m_office_hierarchy,m_office_types WHERE SUPERVISOR_OFFICE_CD IN (SELECT cd FROM temp2)
AND m_office_hierarchy.office_cd=m_office_types.office_cd AND m_office_hierarchy.lang_cd=m_office_types.lang_cd
AND m_office_hierarchy.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' AND m_office_types.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' AND m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD <> 7  AND m_office_hierarchy.OFFICE_CD NOT IN (SELECT cd FROM temp4) AND m_office_hierarchy.OFFICE_CD <> officecd ;
DELETE FROM temp2;
INSERT INTO temp2 SELECT * FROM temp3;
INSERT INTO temp4 SELECT * FROM temp3;
DELETE FROM temp3;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO table_count FROM temp2;
END WHILE;
SELECT DISTINCT cd,M_OFFICE_TYPES.office_name FROM temp1,m_office_types WHERE temp1.cd=m_office_types.office_cd AND m_office_types.record_status <> 'D';
ELSE
SELECT '' ;
END IF ;
DROP TABLE  temp1;
DROP TABLE  temp2;
DROP TABLE  temp3;
DROP TABLE temp4;
END  $$
DELIMITER ;
```

--- Migrated Oracle Procedure ----------------------------------------

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE get_police_statn_for_hierarchy(officecd IN NUMBER,pstsaffcd IN VARCHAR2)
       as
         v_refcur SYS_REFCURSOR;
        table_count  NUMBER(10,0);
        officerInCharge  VARCHAR2(20);
    BEGIN
    -- This procedure was converted on Mon Nov 14 14:57:57 2016 using Ispirer SQLWays 7.0 Build 3434 64bit Licensed to prabhat.gang@gmail.com - prabhat - India (Demo License, Ispirer MnMTK 2015 Mysql to Oracle Database Migration, 1 month, 20161114).

       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' TRUNCATE TABLE temp1 ';
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' TRUNCATE TABLE temp2 ';
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' TRUNCATE TABLE temp3 ';

       INSERT INTO temp1
       SELECT m_office_hierarchy.OFFICE_CD,m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD FROM m_office_hierarchy,m_office_types WHERE SUPERVISOR_OFFICE_CD = officecd
       and m_office_hierarchy.office_cd = m_office_types.office_cd and m_office_hierarchy.lang_cd = m_office_types.lang_cd and m_office_hierarchy.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D'
       and m_office_types.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' and m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD = 7;
       INSERT INTO temp2
       SELECT m_office_hierarchy.OFFICE_CD,m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD FROM m_office_hierarchy,m_office_types WHERE SUPERVISOR_OFFICE_CD = officecd
       and m_office_hierarchy.office_cd = m_office_types.office_cd and m_office_hierarchy.lang_cd = m_office_types.lang_cd
       and m_office_hierarchy.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' and m_office_types.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' and m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD <> 7;
       SELECT COUNT(*) INTO table_count FROM temp2;
       WHILE (table_count > 0) loop
    INSERT INTO temp1
          SELECT m_office_hierarchy.OFFICE_CD,m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD FROM m_office_hierarchy,m_office_types WHERE SUPERVISOR_OFFICE_CD IN(SELECT cd FROM temp2)
          and m_office_hierarchy.office_cd = m_office_types.office_cd and m_office_hierarchy.lang_cd = m_office_types.lang_cd
          and m_office_hierarchy.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' and m_office_types.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' and m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD = 7;
          INSERT INTO temp3
          SELECT m_office_hierarchy.OFFICE_CD,m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD FROM m_office_hierarchy,m_office_types WHERE SUPERVISOR_OFFICE_CD IN(SELECT cd FROM temp2)
          and m_office_hierarchy.office_cd = m_office_types.office_cd and m_office_hierarchy.lang_cd = m_office_types.lang_cd
          and m_office_hierarchy.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' and m_office_types.RECORD_STATUS <> 'D' and m_office_types.OFFICE_TYPE_CD <> 7;
          DELETE FROM temp2;
          INSERT INTO temp2  SELECT * FROM temp3;
          DELETE FROM temp3;
          SELECT COUNT(*) INTO table_count FROM temp2;
          table_count := 100;
       end loop;
       open v_refcur for SELECT DISTINCT cd,M_OFFICE_TYPES.office_name FROM temp1,m_office_types WHERE temp1.cd = m_office_types.office_cd and m_office_types.record_status <> 'D';
       dbms_sql.return_result(v_refcur);

       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' TRUNCATE TABLE temp1 ';
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' TRUNCATE TABLE temp2 ';
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' TRUNCATE TABLE temp3 ';

       close v_refcur; 
    END;
```

Complete **Error log** While ruining above procedure:

ORA-29481: Implicit results cannot be returned to client

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2785

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2779

ORA-06512: at "CAS_USER.GET_POLICE_STATN_FOR_HIERARCHY", line 38

ORA-06512: at line 8

I am new in oracle world, Please help me to resolve above issue so that i can run above procedure to see "v_refcur" SYS_REFCURSOR output OR Result cursor in SQL Developer.

Comment: Why do you need SYS_REFCURSOR? You don't use it in your code. Do you want to output result of the query `SELECT DISTINCT cd,M_OFFICE_TYPES.office_name FROM temp1,m_office_types WHERE temp1.cd = m_office_types.office_cd and m_office_types.record_status <> 'D'`?

Comment: What are `temp1`, `temp2`, and `temp3`?  Are those global temporary tables?  Or are those permanent tables?  It is very odd in Oracle to materialize intermediate results like this.  I expect you don't really need those objects.  If you are using 12.1, you can return an implicit result.  But you'd also need the 12.1 client and an application that knows about implicit result sets which it doesn't appear you have.  You could upgrade your client but it would be much more common to have an `OUT` parameter of type `sys_refcursor`

Comment: Or, even better, to have a function that returns a `sys_refcursor` rather than a procedure.

Comment: If you're _"new in Oracle world"_ please help yourself and start studying [PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm) to learn the basics. I don't know MySQL stored procedures in details but for sure they are very different compared to Oracle. In this particular case the migration tool wrote a poor quality (i.e. _"you're fired"_-type of quality) code that even doesn't work.

Comment: Do I read correctly: `WHILE (table_count > 0) loop /* snip */ table_count := 100; end loop;` ?

Comment: As @user272735 mentioned, `table_count := 100;` isn't in the original procedure. btw I don't know if you have time and budget to refactor the converted code but `temp2` is only used for counting and then immediately deleted. You just count whatever was used to populate it and get rid of temp2 (as seems to have been done with temp4). I suspect you could do this in the original procedure as well.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to your client driver not being updated to 12c. E.g. when calling the stored procedure from Java, make sure you have the latest 12c JDBC driver, not the 11g one.

I've also [documented this in a separate Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42088374/521799) in case this problem here is not related to JDBC.