# ORA-29481: Implicit results cannot be returned to client when calling Oracle 12c procedure from JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, cursor

I wrote a PL/SQL procedure like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_5666 (
  id1 NUMBER := NULL, 
  id2 NUMBER := NULL, 
  id3 NUMBER := NULL
) IS
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
  c2 SYS_REFCURSOR;
  c3 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  IF id1 IS NOT NULL THEN
    OPEN c1 FOR SELECT first_name, last_name FROM t_author WHERE id = id1;
    dbms_sql.return_result (c1);
  END IF;

  IF id2 IS NOT NULL THEN
    OPEN c2 FOR SELECT title FROM t_book WHERE id = id2;
    dbms_sql.return_result (c2);
  END IF;

  IF id3 IS NOT NULL THEN
    OPEN c3 FOR SELECT id3 AS id FROM dual;
    dbms_sql.return_result (c3);
  END IF;
END;
```

And now, I want to call the above procedure from Java using JDBC as follows ([algorithm inspired by this article](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-execute-sql-batches-with-jdbc-and-jooq/) and [this one](http://tkyte.blogspot.ch/2013/07/12c-implicit-result-sets.html)):

```java
try (Connection cn = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver().connect(url, properties);
     Statement s = cn.createStatement()) {
    boolean result = s.execute("begin p_5666(1, 2, 3); end;");

    fetchLoop:
    for (int i = 1;; i++) {

        // Note, this call seems to be required in Oracle even for the first result set.
        // In other JDBC drivers (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server), this would skip the first result
        result = s.getMoreResults();

        if (result)
            try (ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet()) {
                System.out.println("\nResult " + i + ":");
                ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();

                while (rs.next())
                    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, meta.getColumnCount())
                    // Using jOOλ's wrapper for lambdas throwing checked exceptions
                             .mapToObj(Unchecked.intFunction(
                                  j -> meta.getColumnName(j) + ": " + rs.getObject(j)))
                             .forEach(System.out::println);
            }
        else if ((s.getUpdateCount()) == -1)
            break fetchLoop;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the above throws the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-29481: Implicit results cannot be returned to client.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2785
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2779
ORA-06512: at "TEST.P_5666", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was still using an 11g version of the ojdbc driver. Upgrading to a 12c version of ojdbc fixed the problem and yields the expected result:

> Result 1:
> FIRST_NAME: George
> LAST_NAME: Orwell
>
> Result 2:
> TITLE: Animal Farm
>
> Result 3:
> ID: 3

[I've written a blog post that explains how these cursors can be fetched, more in detail](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-fetch-oracle-12c-implicit-cursors-with-jdbc-and-jooq/).